# How to change value of subtitle cell by value returned from subview ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

all I wanna do is to change value of label in specific UITableViewCell by value specified in subview.
I have a uitableviewcell which display product name & available sizes. After clicking on the product cell in my application, I display subview which contains textfield.  I use delegate to pass data from subview like in code below. When I return to the parent view everything is ok  The value of textfield is returned, but I don't know how to change value of label in specific cell after back to parent view. 
PARENT VIEW.m

```
-(void)addSizeToParentView:(SizeViewController*)controller didFinishEnteringSizeInfo:(NSString*)sizeInfo{
NSLog(@"This was returned from sizeViewController: %@",sizeInfo);}    


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"PackageCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        UILabel *productNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 300, 29)];
        productNameLabel.text = [self.choosedProducts objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:productNameLabel];

    UILabel *sizeListLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 25, 300, 15)];
        sizeListLabel.text = @"THIS LABEL SHOULD BE POPULATE BY VALUE OF CHILD VIEW!!"
        UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15];
        sizeListLabel.font = font;
        sizeListLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:sizeListLabel];
    }
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

                [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
                UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
                SizeViewController *sizeViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SizeView"];
                sizeViewController.title = [self.choosedProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                sizeViewController.delegate = self;

                [[self navigationController] pushViewController:sizeViewController animated:YES];
}

SizeViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    setSizes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    self.manager = [[RETableViewManager alloc] initWithTableView:self.tableView];
    self.manager.style.cellHeight = 60;

// Add a section
//
RETableViewSection *section = [RETableViewSection section];
section.headerTitle = @"Specify sizes & quantities";
[self.manager addSection:section];

self.sizes = [RELongTextItem itemWithValue:nil placeholder:@"ex. XL:5, L:10, M:15, S:5, XS:12"];
self.sizes.validators = @[@"presence"];
self.sizes.cellHeight = 200;
    [section addItem:self.sizes];
    self.sizes.onEndEditing = ^(RELongTextItem *size){
        NSLog(@"Value: %@", size.value);
        [self.delegate addSizeToParentView:self didFinishEnteringSizeInfo:size.value];

    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try in ParentView.m:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

how to fill the sizeListLabel? is an nsarray?
to edit the cell to return from sizeViewController, you should replace object at that index of the array.

Comment: Ok but how to change value on specific cell for example after click on product on indexPath.row = 1 I want to change value of label just on this indexpath.row??

Comment: Ilario I will try to do it that way

Comment: I swapped the object in the table but it did not help. size label value has not changed. Is there any other way than using the methods of viewWillAppear?? Regards